# Consecutive calls to two functions in the fetch statment

Tags: javascript

I've got **two functions with fetch calls** in them. When I call them consecutively in a **third function with a fetch statement**. Only one gets called, the other one doesn't get called.

```
reloadOne() {
fetch(...)
...
return;
}

reloadTwo() {
    fetch(...)
    ...
    return;
    }

myOtherFunction()
{
fetch(...).then((res) => { return this.reloadOne(); }).then((res) => { return this.reloadTwo(); }))
}
```

Comment: None of functions `return` a promise

Comment: @HMR Both of them actually don't have anything to return.

Comment: Return the fetch call instead of nothing.

Comment: Are you not seeing any errors, if you don't catch a rejecting promise it should show an error. As Shilly says; you shold return the fetch but if you want to do both of them at the same time then do a `Promise.all([this.reloadOne(),this.reloadTwo()])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the fetch methods so that the promise from them is returned and can be acted upon.

See this example: https://jsbin.com/fijohanoge/edit?js,console

```
function functionOne() {
  console.log('function 1');
  return fetch("https://null.jsbin.com")
  .then(() => {
    console.log('function 1 result');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}

function functionTwo() {
  console.log('function 2');
  return fetch("https://null.jsbin.com")
  .then(() => {
    console.log('function 2 result');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}

console.log('start');
fetch("https://null.jsbin.com")
.catch((err) => { console.error(err); })
.then((res) => {
  console.log('response 1');
  return functionOne();
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('before function 2');
  return functionTwo();
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('after function 2');
  return;
})
```